# Error when trying to mount Azure File storage on a CentOS 7 machine

Tags: azure, mount, server-message-block

Since the general availability of Azure File storage, the file storage can be connected from on-premise machines using SMB 3.0. When I tried to mount the file storage, it gives out a `Permission Denied` error, while I can use the file share with `smbclient` just fine.

```
[root@server mnt]# mount -t cifs -o credentials=/root/smb.pass,vers=
3.0,rw //allendisk.file.core.windows.net/allendisk file/
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Using `smbclient`, it can connect just fine.

```
[root@server mnt]# smbclient //allendisk.file.core.windows.net/allen
disk -mSMB3 -A /root/smb.pass
Domain=[X] OS=[] Server=[]
smb: \>
```

It is confusing that I can connect to the file share but not able to mount on it. My `smbclient` version is 4.1.12 and the cifs kernel module is 6.2.

Answer (score 3):

You will need an SMB client that supports encryption. Have a look at this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-file-storage-now-generally-available/

In that URL, it says:

> Note that since the Linux SMB client doesn’t support encryption yet,
>   mounting from Linux still requires the client to be in the same Azure
>   region as the file share. However, encryption support for Linux is on
>   the roadmap of Linux developers responsible for SMB functionality from
>   the community. Linux distributions that support encryption in the
>   future will be able to mount Azure File Storage from anywhere as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and solved with the steps below:

It is necessary to add the domain parameter on the mount command:

mount -t cifs //allendisk.file.core.windows.net/allendisk /files -o username=john.sample,password=change@123,**domain=CONTOSO**,vers=3.0,rw

or

```
mount -t cifs //allendisk.file.core.windows.net/allendisk /files -o credentials=/root/smb.pass,vers=3.0,rw
```

Content file smb.pass

```
[root@server-sp06 ~]# cat smb.pass
username=john.sample 
password=change@123 
domain=AZURE
```